# Transform column and clean the value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I have this peace of code but I get compile error sub or function not defined

```
Sub FormatData()
'Format data in selected column as text, remove hidden characters, and add leading zeroes to 8-digit values

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    
    'Format column as text
    rng.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    'Remove hidden characters and add leading zeroes
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = Trim(Clean(cell.Value))
        If Len(cell.Value) = 8 Then
            cell.Value = "0" & cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

it should run a macro that convert the column to text after it add leading 0 if the value has just 8 characters.

there could be values such as 123456789 but if user enters 012345678 then Excel deletes the 0 at the beginning if the column or cell is not foramtted as text. so I want to add this 0 back and format the column to text so it stays there but why the error?

Comment: Why are you doing this with vba? You have several easier options to add back leading 0's. https://trumpexcel.com/add-leading-zeroes-excel/

Comment: The error occurs because there is no `Clean` function in VBA. You could use `Application.Clean` or `WorksheetFunction.Clean` instead. Also, `Application.Trim` is superior to just `Trim` i.e. you can use it on an array so you don't have to loop: `rng.Value = Format(Application.Trim(Application.Clean(rng.Value)), "00000000#")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, as Clean is not VBA intrinsic function, but `WorksheetFunction.Clean()` method.

```
Sub FormatData()
'Format data in selected column as text, remove hidden characters, and add leading zeroes to 8-digit values

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Object
    
    Set rng = Selection
    
    'Format column as text
    rng.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    'Remove hidden characters and add leading zeroes
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell.Value))
        If Len(cell.Value) = 8 Then
            cell.Value = "0" & cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set cell = Nothing
  
End Sub
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.clean